# Accessing Another Column By Value ,Pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, indexing, label

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
    Type      Name           Category              
    Bird      Flappy Bird    Air      
    Bird      Pigeon         Air    
    Pokemon   Jerry          Aquatic      
    Pokemon   Mudkip         Aquatic
    Animal    Lion           Terrestrial
    Bird      Pigeon         Air2
```

For the given name like say `"Pigeon"`, I need to access the corresponding value in the category Column i.e it should give me the string `"Air"` .
I have 2 values of `Pigeon` but i need to return "Air" for 2nd observation.

Please note that I am **not using indexing** at all so having something like 2nd observation with `iloc` would'nt do. I need to access it by **value** in the other column.

Or something like **obtaining** the **index** of **"Pigeon"** and **using that** to get the corresponding column value will do.

Comment: Not sure about your "not using indexing" comment since by construction every dataframe has an index...it is not possible to have one without.  In such a case, doesn't `df[df.Name == 'Pigeon'].Category` work?

Comment: Actually that would be better , obtain index of current "Pigeon" and use that index to obtain corresponding value in "category"

Comment: @cwharland your solution works , just add a condition for the index part and frame this in an answer.. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/indexing.html#selection-by-label)

So for you example:

```
df.loc[df.Name == 'Pigeon', 'Category']
```

would give you what you want

Example:

```
In [17]:

import io
import pandas as pd
temp = """Type      Name           Category              
Bird      Flappy_Bird    Air      
Bird      Pigeon         Air    
Pokemon   Jerry          Aquatic      
Pokemon   Mudkip         Aquatic
Animal    Lion           Terrestrial"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), sep='\s+')
df
Out[17]:
      Type         Name     Category
0     Bird  Flappy_Bird          Air
1     Bird       Pigeon          Air
2  Pokemon        Jerry      Aquatic
3  Pokemon       Mudkip      Aquatic
4   Animal         Lion  Terrestrial

[5 rows x 3 columns]
In [19]:

df.loc[df.Name == 'Pigeon','Category']
Out[19]:
1    Air
Name: Category, dtype: object
```

If you have multiple values and just want the first then use [`idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.idxmin.html):

```
In [24]:

df.ix[(df.Name == 'Pigeon').idxmin(),'Category']
Out[24]:
'Air'
```

**EDIT**

So for the case where we have multiple values and you want to access the individual values, you can either check the index values and directly access them:

In [23]:

```
df.loc[df.Name=='Pigeon','Category'].index.values
Out[23]:
array([1, 5], dtype=int64)
In [26]:

df.loc[df.Name=='Pigeon','Category'][5]
Out[26]:
'Air2'
```

OR if you want to loop over them then series has a `iteritems()` method:

```
In [28]:

df.loc[df.Name=='Pigeon','Category'].iteritems()
Out[28]:
[(1, 'Air'), (5, 'Air2')]
```

either of these should satisfy your requirements

Comment: yeah sure.. update your answer . and lets clean the comments section